# Windows phone 8.1 How to create list of string stream?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps

In regular `C# console app` i can easily get string from a text file and manipulate it to such way i can make lists with each words in the text, however, with `windows phone 8.1 sdk` it's not using the exact same stuff from console application, here's what i tried and wont work :

*goal: grab the data from a txt file and `string.split(',').tolist()`;

```
private async Task WriteToFile()
{
    // Get the text data from the textbox. 
    byte[] fileBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(this.textBox1.Text.ToCharArray());

    // Get the local folder.
    StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

    // Create a new folder name DataFolder.
    var dataFolder = await local.CreateFolderAsync("DataFolder",
        CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

    // Create a new file named DataFile.txt.
    var file = await dataFolder.CreateFileAsync("DataFile.txt",
    CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    // Write the data from the textbox.
    using (var s = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
    {
        var test1 = s.ToString().ToList();

        s.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
        var wtf = s.Split(',').ToList();

        var Kuma = file.ToString();


        this.textBlock1.Text = wtf[0];

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are doing the `.Split(',').ToList();` on s which is of the type `Stream`

you should do it on the string itself. so on the textbox.Text property itself you could do this:

```
var wtf = this.textBox1.Text.Split(',').ToList();
```

also it's not clear to me why you trying to split up this string AFTER writing it to the file. do the string manipulation at the very start. Also your code does not contain anything to retrieve data from a text file. you're only WRITING not READING